# Trying to understand a Bash script given to me, specifically the while loop

Tags: bash, do-while, chemistry

I am using a script made by one of my former colleagues, he told me I'll need some working with it. I am wondering what this while loop does:

```
# This is the loop that does the simulation
lastsim=0
nextsim=`/usr/bin/expr $lastsim + 1`

while [ $nextsim -le $upperlimit ]
do

  cp -i Dynamics_${lastsim}_500ps/*.prmtop ./$paramInput.prmtop
```

specifically I'm confused by thie -le syntax
This is only part of the script I can upload the rest if necessary.

Comment: Read here: [Integer comparison in Shell](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/comparing-numbers-in-bash-shell/)

Comment: What exactly confuses you?

Comment: Also: `help test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-le` means *less or equal to*. See the following example which would print 0-9:

```
i=0
while [ $i -le 9 ]; do
  echo $i
  let i++
done
```